Best First search to find the path from start to goal on a grid that has unassigned cost. Heuristic values
I'm trying to answer this challenge:

Consider the problem of finding a path in the grid shown in this figure from the position  to the position :

A piece can move on the grid horizontally or vertically, one square at a time. No step may be made into a forbidden shaded area.
Using best-first search, nodes are expanding from  to . Manhattan distance should be used as the evaluation function. The Manhattan distance between two points is the distance in the -direction plus the distance in the -direction. It corresponds to the distance travelled along city streets arranged in a grid. Assume multiple-path pruning. What is the first path found?

I tried the following approach, but I am not sure since there are no heuristic values given:

How can I determine what the first path found is?

Would you like to add your code so that we see where your problems are?  see here

Assuming you are referring to the greedy best-first search as described on Wikipedia, you have expanded too many squares at the right side of the grid, while you have not expanded enough squares at the left side, which would be expanded by the best-first algorithm.
Let's do this step by step so I can show why that is. I omitted one black square on these images (by accident), but it plays no significant role so I decided not to redo the images:
After going for the promising squares at Manhattan distance 3 and 2, we cannot further expand that square with distance 2:

The expandable square with the least distance has distance 3, and expands to the right. After that we have two squares at distance 4 which expand to their neighbors, which are all three at distance 5. Then these are expanded, which gives us this state:

Here we have a square at distance 4, which gets priority over the other squares with distance 6. We thus expand that square to two neighbors which get distance 5. These two are now the ones with priority, and we expand those to three new squares:

Again we get some squares with distance 6, but there is a new one with distance 4, so it gets priority, and is expanded to a square with distance 5. That latter square has now priority and expands to a square with distance 4, which takes the priority. At this point it becomes clear we will never expand any square with distance 6, since the distances of the new squares we will expand at the left side of the grid will all have less distance:

The square with distance 4 at the left expands into a square with distance 3, getting the priority. It expands into two squares with distance 2, getting the priority:

These two squares will expand into two squares, including the left neighbor of "g". It depends on the order in which these 2-squares will be expanded which path will be registered. I will assume here that the lower 2-square will be expanded first:

The goal square has now been found and we can reconstruct the shortest path from the direction in which each involved square was expanded, following the arrows in opposite sense back to the source square. And so we get this path:

Again, the step from 3 to 2 could have gone the alternative way as well. It depends on information you have not given: the order in which squares are expanded when they have equal priority.
Also note that there was no further expansion of squares at the right and bottom sides of the grid, since their priority was never high enough.
